# Why didn't work RTCPeerConnection icegatheringstatechange?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backbone.js, webrtc

I use icegatheringstatechange event handler, but he didn't work. How I can catch icegatheringstate change? How do I know that all ice candidates added?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

The `icegatheringstatechange` event isn't implemented in all browsers (actually, I'm not aware of where it is implemented, but it's not implemented in Firefox). That's why your event handler isn't called.

If you want to know when all ice candidates are added, there will be an `icecandidate` event dispatched with `event.candidate = null`.

Here's the description of this behavior from [the current editor's draft of the WebRTC spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcpeerconnectioniceevent-candidate):

> ***candidate*** of type *RTCIceCandidate*, readonly , nullable
>
> ...
>
> This attribute is set to `null` when an event is generated to indicate the end of candidate gathering.

Comment: Thank you dear stranger!